# Escape velocity from Earth and sphere of influence

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

I know that *escape Velocity* from the Earth's surface is 11.2 km/s.
But is that the minimum velocity to get to ***orbit*** (L.E.O I guess) or to escape ***Earth's sphere of influence***?

Comment: Gravitational forces extend out to infinity, so shouldn't that mean the sphere of influence is also technically infinite?

Comment: It's effect reduces drastically, take the formula for field GM/r², as r increases 1/r² reduces largely. Hence it's effect is not that pronounced.

Comment: I know. But technically it only approaches 0 as r increases. So it is never exactly zero, meaning the influence is technically infinite.

Comment: The sphere of influence would be infinite if there was nothing else in the universe.  In the case of the Earth, there is the Sun.  Get far enough from the Earth and the Sun's gravity will be more significant.  If you just achieve escape velocity from the Earth then you will orbit the Sun.  To escape it, you will need to be much faster again.

Answer (score 1):

[**Escape velocity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) is defined as the minimum initial velocity of a body at which, if it is launched, it will never return back to earth. This is the speed for a non-propelled object to escape from the gravitational influence(i.e., to take the object to an infinite distance from the planet) of a planet(like earth) or any other huge body.
Now this is the formula to calculate the escape velocity:
$$v_e=\sqrt{\frac{2GM_P}{r}}$$Where,
$v_e$ is the escape velocity,
$G$ is the *Gravitational constant*,
$M_P$ is the mass of the planet,
$r$ is the distance of the body from the center of mass of the planet($≈$ the radius of the planet, $R_P$).
For earth, the escape velocity is $≈ 11.2km/s$.

And what you're looking for is the [**Orbital speed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed). It is the speed at which a body(more appropriately, a satellite) rotates around the [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) another huge body(like a planet). Now, you may think what has the orbital speed got do with your question. But, believe me or not they're the same.
How come they're the same?
That's a long story. However I might try to explain how it works. When you launch something tangentially to earth's surface, it will be pulled back by earth's gravity. When you keep increasing the speed at some point it will go on to rotate around earth not falling into earth. This speed will be the minimum speed to launch a satellite to  the lowest orbit. Right?
And that's the same speed we're talking about.
This, is the formula to calculate the orbital speed:
$$v_0 = \sqrt{\frac{GM_P}{r}}$$  Where,
$v_0$ is the orbital speed,
$G$ is the *Gravitational constant*,
$M_P$ is the mass of the planet,
$r$ is the distance of the body from the center of mass of the planet($=$ the radius of the planet + the height of the satellite i.e, $R_P+h$).
For Earth, the orbital velocity(for the Low Earth Orbital) is $≈ 8km/s$.

Now, actually this escape velocity isn't really required for a propelled object like a rocket to travel into space i.e., normally rockets never reach escape velocity.
But, how do they reach space?
The reason is that they keeps adding Kinetic Energy by burning more fuel. So they can escape the gravitational influence of a planet any desired speed provided that they should have enough propellant to supply acceleration against the planet's acceleration due to gravity.

To know more about Orbital speed, see [this article by The Physics Classroom](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/mmedia/vectors/sat.cfmcenter)

Comment: Oh wow! Now I get it!! Yeah I needed that minimum velocity required to get in orbit 'cause I was confusing it with escape Velocity from earth to escape Velocity from atmosphere! Thanks

Comment: The amosphere will complicate things.  The simple formula for escape velocity ignores it.  So, if there is an atmosphere then you will need to launch even faster to compensate for the drag.  Then you have the problem of getting hot (like a spacecraft on reentry).  Jules Verne's technique of getting to the Moon would not really work.  The crew would killed on launch and then get cremated shortly afterwards.

Comment: Leave this poor man, @badjohn. I'm not actually planning to launch a spaceship. And neither do I think that the questioner is.

Comment: @ashayM. Don't you think that my answer is worth accepting?

Comment: My important point was that the atmosphere complicates matters and that your formulae ignore it.  The OP seemed to think that escape velocity meant fast enough to leave the atmosphere.  Not only does it not mean that, it would probably be infeasible to get out of the atmosphere without an engine.  Mention of Jules Verne and astronauts was just a humorous illustration.

Comment: Guys chill! Both have their respective points, but yes I don't plan to leave the atmosphere :)!  @lee yes you gave a very nice context! Loved it! Got my doubts thanks to you! badjohn you are funny :) you guys on twitter?

Comment: Guys chill! Both have their respective points, but yes I don't plan to leave the atmosphere :)!  lee yes you gave a very nice context! Loved it! Got my doubts thanks to you! @badjohn you are funny :) you guys on twitter?

Comment: I'm quite chilled.  Lee's answer is good but I just thought that it could be a little better by mentioning the atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

Escape velocity is the velocity needed to escape a body's gravitational influence. Since gravity has (in theory) infinite reach, this means that if an object reaches escape velocity, it will never return to that object and would forever move away from it.

Escape velocity is mathematically described by

$$V=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$$

while the velocity required to reach orbit (orbital velocity) is

$$V=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Others have given good answers but I'd like to add a bit. As the others have said, the escape velocity is given by:

$$V=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$$

I don't need to add to the other answers about that.

What, I'd like to add that this is more of theoretical than practical interest.  It is not the the velocity required to get to space (whatever that may mean), in particular it is not the velocity required to get out of the atmosphere, to LEO, or out of the Earth's sphere of influence.

So, what is it?  It is the velocity that would be required to escape from Earth in these conditions: there is no atmosphere, there is nothing else in the universe, and no force (other than the Earth's gravity) is applied after launch.  If launched at exactly the escape velocity then a projectile would gradually slow as it receded but it would never quite stop.  Conversely, it is the speed that an object would hit Earth if dropped from extremely far away with no initial velocity (with respect to the Earth).  Again, with the assumption of no atmosphere, no other objects in the universe, and no force (other than the Earth's gravity) applied.

Back to the real world with atmosphere and other objects in the universe.

Obviously, the atmosphere will slow the projectile considerably so it would need considerably more initial velocity to escape. For the Earth, this would be so much that most materials would melt or vaporise. Consider how hot spacecraft get on reentry.  For the Moon this won't apply.  For Mars, it might only need a small adjustment.

For the Earth, a significant other object is the Sun with its considerably greater gravity.  Your $11.2kms^{-1}$ would get you away from the Earth but not the Sun.  You would remain in the Solar System. You would need the considerably higher velocity of $42.1kms^{-1}$ to escape the Sun.  Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) is quite good.

This is where the [sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence_(astrodynamics)) comes in.  It is the distance from a body where its gravity is most significant.  It depends both on the body itself and others around it.  If the Earth were the only body in the universe then its sphere of influence would infinite.  Even a billion light years away, it would cause a tiny attraction.

So, how do we manage to get to space if the escape velocity would melt the craft and the acceleration required would destroy the payload?  The answer is that you use an engine.  With an engine, you don't need any particular velocity.  You could ascend at a walking pace with a suitable engine and enough fuel.  Why don't we do that?  Why are rockets fast (though not escape velocity fast)?  Well, the problem is that you need to carry the fuel and that is very expensive.  The faster that you initially accelerate, the less fuel you have to carry for the remainder of the trip.  So, you launch as fast as your craft and its contents will tolerate.  If in an atmosphere, some further drag considerations may apply.  Launching from the Moon is easier than from the Earth.

Comment: can I follow you on twitter or something, I like your misc unique thinking! :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Twitter or anything like that.